# redirect_to inside redirect_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line inside code

```
redirect_to "#{Housing.authentication_service_url_public}?redirect_to=#{CGI.escape(request.original_url)}"
```

can anyone explain why is another redirect_to inside redirect_to?

I understand that redirect_to is used for calling for a specific method of specific controller.

I don't understand what this line does?

Comment: If the `redirect_to` in the query string isn't evaluated, then is just a simple string going through your params, you shouldn't care.

Comment: @SebastianPalma what do you mean by evaluated?

Comment: `redirect_to` is a method in Rails, and in Ruby you can evaluate strings, meaning `eval('1+1') # => 2`. So, if that "redirect_to" in the argument of `redirect_to` which is a string, isn't evaluated/executed, then is just that, a simple string.

Comment: @SebastianPalma value of CGI.escape(request.original_url) is  http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F